# Enable browser caching in JSP

Tags: jsp, http-headers, jboss7.x, browser-cache, developer-tools

How can I define my content of a page cacheable? I am using Google Chromes Audit function and it tells me:

```
The following resources are explicitly non-cacheable. Consider making them cacheable if possible.
```

I created a new `Filter` that is called with every request:

```
public class CachingFilter implements Filter {

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private");
        httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", System.currentTimeMillis() + 604800000L); // one week
        httpResponse.setDateHeader("Max-Age", System.currentTimeMillis() + 604800000L);

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

This `Filter` works for all JavaScript files, because they don't appear in the Google Audit tool anymore. But I still get a list of images and the main JSP file. What other headers do I have to set to also enable caching for them?

This is the `Request-Header` of an image:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:entries=20; JSESSIONID=fSSOjMOknqW4yk0bH1Nxy2Ea.undefined
Host:localhost:8080
If-Modified-Since:Mon, 13 Aug 2012 12:52:32 GMT
If-None-Match:W/"1685-1344862352945"
Referer:http://localhost:8080/SSIS2_JBoss7/View/PackageManagement/Packages.jsp
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.79 Safari/537.1
```

And the `Response-Header` of the image:

```
Cache-Control:private
Date:Thu, 16 Aug 2012 08:33:05 GMT
ETag:W/"1685-1344862352945"
Expires:Thu, 23 Aug 2012 08:33:05 GMT
Max-Age:Thu, 23 Aug 2012 08:33:05 GMT
Pragma:No-cache
```

Comment: Are you sure that the Chrome Audit is referring the JSP file itself and not the CSS/JS/image resources which is in turn referenced by the HTML output which is generated by the JSP? If the latter, then you obviously need to set the headers on the responses of those resources and not on the response of the JSP.

Comment: Yes, Chrome Audit is referring to the JSP file, to images (png, gif), to JavaScript files and to CSS files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add this line in order to cache all images and the main JSP file:

```
httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "private");
```